# DJango, custom filter with list_display custom method

Tags: django

I'm trying to filter by the custom method i made for `language` column.  In `admin.py` i have the following;

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

class MovieAdminModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields= ('title_en')
    list_display = ('get_language',)
    list_filter = ('get_language')

    def get_language(self, obj):
        if obj.language==1:
            return 'Persian With English Subtitle'
        else:
            return 'Persian'
        
    get_language.admin_order_field = "language"
    get_language.short_description = "language"
```

In `list_filter` i use `get_language` and this error is returned **The value of 'list_filter[0]' refers to 'get_language', which does not refer to a Field.**  If i use `language` in `list_filter` , the filters shows `yes` or `no`.  Filter should show either `Persian With English Subtitle` or `Persian`. How do i solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a [custom admin filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/filters/#using-a-simplelistfilter) for this task, something like this:

```py
from django.contrib.admin import SimpleListFilter

class LanguageFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'Language'
    parameter_name = 'language'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return [
            ('Persian With English Subtitle', 'Persian With English Subtitle'),
            ('Persian', 'Persian')
        ]

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        value = self.value()
        if value == 'Persian With English Subtitle':
            return queryset.filter(language=1)
        return queryset.exclude(language=1)

class MovieAdminModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (
        LanguageFilter,
    )
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, what does this line mean `return queryset.exclude(language=1)`?

Comment: @user892134 it is the same as: `select * from <table_name> where language != 1`

Comment: i don't need this line then, because `return queryset.filter(language=1)` is `select * from <table_name> where language = 1`?

Comment: Yes. I assumed that if `language == 1` is "Persian with Subtitle", then all other records are "Persian"